# Java - Detecting client crash with RMI

Tags: java, crash, client, rmi

I have created a RMI connection but I do not know how to notify the server when the client ends or crashes. I have found the *unreferenced()* method, but it does not work. Any idea?

(the server is multiclient, there is only one kind of object passed to the client but any client has a different instance of it).
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with that is that if the client crashes, it's hard to have it do anything, and you end up waiting for timeouts.

The usual solution is to set up a "heartbeat", a periodic call; if the client heartbeat doesn't get to you after, say, 2 periods, you figure it's dead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This mechanism was my last choice, since I hoped there was a better alternative. Anyway, how can the server call the client? The server, by now, uses only:    LocateRegistry.createRegistry(RMI_PORT);
Naming.rebind(...);
Is there a method to "ping" the client?
Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

The unreferenced() method does indeed work, but it takes the DGC time interval before it does so. This varies with JDK version. Last time I looked it was ten minutes. There are system properties to control this, see the Java RMI Home Page. This facility would be used via a client-specific RemoteSession object that implements the API the client needs, keeps track of client state, and implements Unreferenced as a failsafe against the client failing to keep itself alive or logout via its API.

There is no other reliable way to detect a client crash other than keeping track of when they last called you, unless you have client-side callbacks, in which case the server can try calling the client. However these are widely viewed as a security risk and generally don't work through firewalls without special treatment.